# How to query a MySQL field that has a string containing a double pipe?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table has a field which contains double pipes `"||"`

I'm not sure how to get the query to recognise the pipes.  I guess they are not being interpreted as string literals.

`WHERE field LIKE '||%value%||'`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what problem have you found? Pipes do not have any special meaning inside a SQL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe character has no special meaning, neither in a string literal, nor in a `like` pattern.

Are you really looking for a value that starts and ends with two pipe characters, and contains `value` somehere between them? For examle `||asdfvalueqerty||`.

If you are looking for a value that contains `||value||`, you would use the pattern `'%||value||%'` instead.

Comment: /facepalm |

It's been a long day.